# .NET, convert png file into RGBA 32bit Bitmap, in memory

Tags: c#, .net, imaging

```
var image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\image.png");
```

How do I convert this into a `Bitmap` in rgba32b format?

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap original = new Bitmap(@"C:\image.png");
Bitmap clone = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);

using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(clone)) {
    gr.DrawImage(original, new Rectangle(0, 0, clone.Width, clone.Height));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The Save method can specify the format, so you can just save it out to a memory stream.

Comment: I see this method. ```void Save(Stream stream, ImageFormat format)```. How do I specify the pixel format?